# Easy way to get metric matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, metric

Let's say I have a vector of strings and I wrote a function which find a distance between two strings.

I want to get the matrix of distances determined by this function.
I know the brute-force way of doing it with loops but is there another simplier path?

For example:

my function:

```
function [value] = func(str1, str2)
    value = abs(str1(1) - str2(1))
end
```

the grueling way of getting the metric matrix

```
v = ['str'; 'rew'; 'ter'];
num = length(v);
metrMat = zeros(num);
for ii = 1:num
    for jj = 1:num
        metrMat(ii,jj) = func(v(ii),v(jj));
    end
end
metrMat

>metrMat =

>     0     1     1
>     1     0     2
>     1     2     0
```

Comment: Share the code that you tried, sample input data and expected output with it?

Comment: @Divakar, I've updated the question with an example

Comment: What is the actual definition of distance between strings that you use? Depending on that, the code can be vectorized or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be one [`vectorized approach`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
metrMat = abs(bsxfun(@minus,v(:,1),v(:,1).'))
```

Sample run -

```
>> v
v =
str
rew
ter
>> metrMat = abs(bsxfun(@minus,v(:,1),v(:,1).'))
metrMat =
     0     1     1
     1     0     2
     1     2     0
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you so reluctant to use for loops? They are pretty fast.

Taking advantage of the symmetry property of the metric matrix, the for loop could be improved:

```
for ii = 1:num
    for jj = 1:ii
        metrMat(ii,jj) = func(v(ii),v(jj));
    end
end

metrMat = metrMat + tril(metrMat)'
```

If you have access to the statistical toolbox this could be achieved in one line:

```
metrMat = squareform(pdist(v(1:num)'));
```